# Setting ID attribute of input field when using ActiveField in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to set a custom `id` for an `input` field whilst using [ActiveField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activefield.html) in `Yii2`.

I tried the below, but it instead set the `id` of the field container instead of the `input` field itself.

```
$form->field($model, 'some_id', ['options' => ['id' => 'some_id']])->hiddenInput(['value' => $some_id])->label(false);
```

Is there a way I can set the `id` attribute of the input field itself?

I noticed the [inputOptions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#$inputOptions-detail) option, but this seems to control the setting for all the fields, so unsure how it works exactly with the selectors etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `id` key to options array you've already passed in to `hiddenInput` method

```
$form->field($model, 'some_id')->hiddenInput(['value' => $some_id, 'id' => 'some_id'])->label(false);
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks. Guess I forgot about that haha and was looking for the more general way to do it.